# Visual Studio checking naming convention for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, naming-conventions, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I'm trying to configure my Visual Studio 022 to check and put warning when my compagny C++ code rules et naming conventions are not respected. The simple example is to prefix boolean with a "b".

`bool bFoo = true`

I tried to configure Visual Studio with the `.editorconfig`. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/lnt-naming-convention?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=msvc-173)  in the Microsoft Documentation. And I created this :

```
[*.{cpp,h}]
cpp_naming_rule.booleans_prefixed.symbols                 = boolean_vars
cpp_naming_rule.booleans_prefixed.style                   = boolean_style

cpp_naming_symbols.boolean_vars.applicable_kinds          = local,parameter,field
cpp_naming_symbols.boolean_vars.applicable_type           = bool

cpp_naming_style.boolean_style.capitalization              = pascal_case
cpp_naming_style.boolean_style.required_prefix             = b
cpp_naming_style.boolean_style.required_suffix             =
cpp_naming_style.boolean_style.word_separator              =
```

But it does not work. (The file is taken into account, I checked by modifying the indent_size).

Have any ideas to fix the editorconfig or to solve my base problem ?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? If I recall, this will not cause compilation errors, but just IntelliSense issues when the file is open. You also have to turn it on in the Options (by default, it is a "suggestion"). Also note, that it is "experimental" so might not actually work all the time.

Comment: clang-tidy can do that sort of thing.

Comment: Please, don't. A proper adjective phrase should be used for boolean identifiers instead of Hungariang notation.

Answer (score 0):

> Introduced in Visual Studio 2022 17.7

1. Check your Visual Studio version. Try resetting Visual Studio Settings.
2. Place `.editorconfig` in the same folder as the project. Then add `.editorconfig` into project.  Add -> Existing   item.
3. Check the settings:  Naming Convention setting in the C/C++ Code Style options and [Configure the linter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/cpp-linter-overview?view=msvc-170#configure-the-linter).   It is recommended to change it to Warning or Error. But this doesn't affect the compiler, just the editor.  White is not obvious

[image]

4. Wait for Visual Studio to load `.editorconfig`. It may take a long time until the font changes from white to green.

[image]